# MySQL many-to-many relationship table usage

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have three tables: Resumes, Orgs, and Resume2Org. Basically, Resume2Org is my many-to-many relationship table linking Resumes.resume_id to Orgs.org_id (so it only has those two keys in that table).

My question is, is it okay to use that many-to-many relationship table to store other data? My use case: the database is part of a system to sift through incoming resumes. But I've been asked to implement a "marked as read" feature so we can easily get the list of resumes we haven't looked at yet. But since a resume can belong to many different orgs, we only want to mark a resume as read for the org the user/viewer belongs to. I thought, hey, having that flag in Resume2Org would be perfect. Is this a smart approach, or should I create a new table specifically for "marked as read"? All the examples I've seen about many-to-many relationship tables is that those tables are used just for that... linking two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is okey to have additional fields in a many-to-many table. I think it is the right way to do in your case as you don't need to join additional tables and you save spaces.

I was in a very similar situation last week and I added additional field for that.

Comment: Thanks! I just didn't know if it was against best practices or whatnot.